# Ruby on Rails database column output is mangled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, gis

I'm connecting my Rails app to a SQL Server database that I *do not* control. One of the tables has a column of the type `geometry`. I can view it, and in BeeKeeper Studio just fine, but when I attempt to view the column/attribute in my Rails console, I get garbled output.

Here is some of the data as seen in BeeKeeper Studio:

```json
{"srid":4248,"version":1,"points":[{"x":-60.161088,"y":4.53526,"z":null,"m":null},{"x":-60.160342,"y":...
```

And here is some of the output from the Rails console:

```rb
\x98\u0010\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0004\xE5\b\u0000\u0000\x97\xE3\u0015\x88\x9E\u0014N\xC0\x87m\
```

Now, Rails tells me that that string is encoded as "UTF-8" -- I find that hard to believe.

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong here? I get the feeling that either Rails is doing something bad to the string when it's taken from the database, or that I need to specify some encoding/collation in my database settings, but I don't know what.

If it helps, the database, and table's collation are both "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS".

Comment: The short version: Ruby is lying to you.

Comment: The longer version: GEOGRAPHY, GEOMETRY and HIERARCHYID types are binary encoded data that's typically returned to clients in `varbinary(max)` values - unless they have done something like `select geometryValue.STAsText()` to return a textual representation. BeeKeeper Studio is apparently decoding the binary data to present in JSON format. The binary encoding is documented in [MS-SSCLRT: Microsoft SQL Server CLR Types Serialization Formats](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-ssclrt/77460aa9-8c2f-4449-a65e-1d649ebd77fa). Find a library that supports these types.

Comment: Interesting! I was able to get legible output by doing this: `Model::select('Geometry.STAsText() as geo').first.geo`. That gave me `POLYGON ((-60.161088 4.53526, -60.160342 4.536124, -60.15906...`. I suppose I may still end up having to parse that using some third-party library, so I could return something useful in my controllers.

Comment: I ended up cheating slightly, and using regex to parse that output so I could build my own JSON object. That isn't the ideal answer, so I won't include it as such on this question. Hopefully, someone in the future can provide the proper solution.